# Locked out of access database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I created a database and disabled the 'shift' bypass. I also have an AutoExec module that is running on a constant loop and quits the application.

Is there anyway to counter this or change the vba code?

Comment: It doesn't really help you right now but if I'm doing the shift bypass I tend to add it on right before deployment and save a separate version without that on for this kind of eventuality. This experience may make you adopt the same approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press Ctrl + Break - This should let you in to the background code by breaking the code and debugging

Hope this helps

Comment: OMG. David you have save my bacon. This actually works. Seemed too simple but I defo owe you.

Comment: Apologies, I was assuming your code was stuck in a loop which was preventing you from using Ctrl + Break.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vba to edit the properties from outside

```
opendatabase("yourdbfullname").properties!Allowbypasskey = true
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as I was curious. This doesn't work sadly. Unless by me adding this into a VBA Module is the wrong approach