# Completely locked up my Access database?

Tags: ms-access

[image: Locked out?]

I think I may have completely messed up my application here! I was foolishly playing around with some settings in the File > Options menu for Access and turned a couple of things off. It said I needed to close and re-open, so I did, and now I can't do or edit anything. How do I revert back?

Right clicking the window doesn't help, I tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to switch to VBA but that doesn't help. I disabled the close button on the form already, so can't click the X.

I have spent hours working on this, and feel like I may have to start again.

Any ideas how I can get back into my file?

Comment: what version of access? I don't suppose you can right-click and restore from a previous version?

Comment: Should you ever disable the Shift-Bypass too, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522832/locked-out-of-access-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you double click on the file; hold down SHIFT key.

When you open a database while holding down the SHIFT key, many of the options that you set on the Current Database page of the Access Options dialog box are bypassed.

Once you have bypassed these settings you can access your ribbons and options to reset your settings.

Comment: Genius! I was so worried I would not get back all of my work. Thank you.